# Organising a multidimensional unorder list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, organization

I have an `ul -> ul ...` list and want to organised it, It's a bit strange design but its the one that fitts:

```
<ul id="files">
    <li class="folder">
        <span>folder 5</span>
        <ul>
            <li class="folder">
                <span>folder</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="folder">
                        <span>folder</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="file">file1.js</li>
                            <li class="file">file2.js</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <li class="file">file.js</li>
            </li>
            <li class="folder">
                <span>folde1r</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="file">file3.js</li>
                    <li class="file">file4.js</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="folder">
                <span>folde2</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="file">file3.js</li>
                    <li class="file">file4.js</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="file file.js">file5.js</li>
    <li class="file file.js">file2.js</li>
    <li class="file file.js">file1.js</li>
</ul>
```

So folders organised first, then files withing folders, regular file list order (a-z) I looked at tiny sort http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/ - but that's only good for single `ul>li` list.

```
$('#files li span').tsort();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CezarisLT/8bK3f/

Can anyone help?

Comment: Isn't `$('li').tsort();` giving you the right results? http://jsfiddle.net/wMBkL/

Comment: @sroes I have no idea how that works but it does, thank you, Post it as an answer and explain how and ill give you the +50. Like how do's it know to move the folders up to the top?

Comment: Don't rely on the DOM for that, it is slow and inefficient. Do your logic in js using proper objects/arrays, then render everything just once. Use either Backbone.js, Angular.js, Ember.js...but no jQuery.

Comment: See my answer. The above was working because in your HTML, the folders are already above the files (per ul). In my answer I also explained how to always force folders above files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#files li span')` does not match all the elements in the list. Try the following instead:

```
$('#files li').tsort();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WRqaE/

If you also need to sort the folders, you can provide a custom sort function to always put folders above files:

```
$('#files li').tsort('', {
    sortFunction: function(a, b) {
        if (a.e.hasClass('folder') && !b.e.hasClass('folder')) {
            return -1;
        } else if (!a.e.hasClass('folder') && b.e.hasClass('folder')) {
            return 1;
        }
        return a.s === b.s ? 0 : (a.s > b.s ? 1 : -1);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pC24j/